django-modeltranslation choice field issue
I'm having a problem using the application django-modeltranslation with a choice field.
My model Plan has a field called interval with the following choices:
class IntervalChoices(models.TextChoices):
    DAY = DATE_INTERVALS.DAY, _("Day")
    WEEK = DATE_INTERVALS.WEEK, _("Week")
    MONTH = DATE_INTERVALS.MONTH, _("Month")
    YEAR = DATE_INTERVALS.YEAR, _("Year")

class Plan(SoftDeleteBasedMixin):
    INTERVALS = IntervalChoices
    interval = models.CharField(
      choices=INTERVALS.choices,
      max_length=12,
      default=INTERVALS.MONTH,
      help_text="The frequency with which a subscription should be billed.",
    )

I'm using django-modeltranslation to translate the label and the description of the plan on the admin by directly typing them on the Django Admin, but since those choices are preset I cannot edit them in the Admin.
I already used gettextlazy on the choices names and have the translations on the django.po

#:plan.py:44 msgid "Day" msgstr "Dia"
#:plan.py:45 msgid "Week" msgstr "Semana"
#:plan.py:46 msgid "Month" msgstr "Mês"
#:plan.py:47 msgid "Year" msgstr "Ano"

But when I change both the site or the admin to Portuguese, which is one of the languages I'm translating to the interval is shown in English.
This is my translation.py
from billing.models.plan import Plan
from modeltranslation.translator import TranslationOptions, register


@register(Plan)
class PlanTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ("label", "description")

Can someone help me to see how can I proceed with this?

Have you run python manage.py compilemessages command after adding translations?

Yes. All the other translation are already working.

Try to check if translations work in your shell:
python manage.py shell,
from django.utils.translation import activate, gettext_lazy as _,
activate('pt') or the code defined for Portuguese,
print(_('Day')).
Do you get 'Dia' as an output?
Also, please provide your settings.py configurations

Well, when I do what you said in the shell Im getting the following outputs (I have made a few more for test)
In [3]: print(_('Day'))
Day
In [4]: print(_('Name'))
Nome
In [7]: print(_('Schedule'))
Cronograma
Some words are being translated and other don't

I've noticed that the words in the templates are getting translated correctly but the model names, form fields and etc are not
